# Why default gateway not available keeps happening like every 2 minutes?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, gateway

I  don't know what's the problem in laptops. Every two minutes I have to either run network troubleshooter or I have to disable and enable WiFi adapter. This problem occurs only when I use the WiFi at home, but nowhere else. What could be causing this ?

Sometimes it also shows the following error message:

> The connection between your access point , router or cable modem and the Internet is broken

Here what troubleshooter detects:

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Maybe your local wifi just has bad reception, are you far away from it, is there a lot of other neighbouring (interfering) wifi, or other "noise", maybe your router needs a reboot every few days/hours?

Comment: to all your questions  , no , as for rebooting router I tried it but didn't seem to fix the problem , actually it was fine before , this month this problem appeared

Comment: Expanding on @Xen2050's comment, things to try are: (1) use 2.4Ghz instead of 5GHz, if relevant; (2) try setting the router's wireless channel manually to different frequencies over the range; and (3) use a WiFi extender based on power-line networking.

Comment: it was set to 2.4ghz already  and i tried setting channel manually but the problem occurred again @AFH

Comment: It’s not clear. Are there other computers/devices using this WiFi with the same trouble?

Comment: @Appleoddity yes my brothers laptop has the same problem , but on phones the wifi never interrupts thats why I am confused  , but I know that the problem is not with the laptops because this problem is occurring only when we use wifi at home nowhere else

Comment: It definitely looks like radio interference. Do the 'phones also use 2.4GHz? Did you (or a neighbour, if nearby) install any new electrical/electronic equipment (eg Christmas present) at the time the problem started?

Comment: @AFH no we didn't install any such equipment , and I don't know where I can check if phones use 2.4GHz

Comment: I configure separate SSIDs for 2.4 and 5GHZ, both allowing auto-connect. This allows me to select a specific band, if I choose, or see in the device which it has chosen.

Comment: well I have only 1 for 2.4 so I guess all connect to that one @AFH

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that your 'phones recover silently from interruptions in the WiFi connection. There may be programs that you can run in the background to monitor the router link and try to reconnect repeatedly if there is a break. It can probably be done with a PowerShell script, but that's not my area of expertise.